# VScode Golang output to debug console is buffered and not flushed even on a breakpoint

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm debugging a loop in which each iteration outputs a line and then hits a breakpoint.
I need to see that output line when the breakpoint is hit, although the output is buffered in the debug console so it doesn't flush for several lines, **how do I manage to make it flush on every iteration, or when hitting a breakpoint?**
I'm pretty sure it's not a code problem because if I run the program and use a fmt.Scan() to pause execution on each iteration, the output is flushed correctly each time.
It seems to be an issue with the debug console, go debugger *Delve* or the Microsoft Go extension. **Can I configure the buffering of this console in vscode?**